# SSIS Logging Using DTS.Events

Tags: ssis

I am running SSIS packages on SQL Server 2016 and am trying to log events using Dts.Events.FireInformation and Dts.Events.FireWarning. While these do show in the local IDE progress section, they are not appearing in the SSISDB Logs (e.g. R-Click on a package / Select Reports / All Execution). I also tried Dts.Log() but that didn't write either. I've used logging in the past (circa 2008R2) to the old ssis logging table. I know I can use that but would rather keep these all in oneplace.

Logging level is "Basic" which should pump out both OnInformation and OnWarning.

I did look at this post [on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775625/ssis-logging-in-sql-2012) which looks like it had a viable answer; however, the link to that answer is dead.

Is this just not possible to do or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When the packages run in Visual Studio, the Information and Warning events are logged to both the Package Results tab as well as the Output window.

That data only gets recorded into the SSISDB if the server is the one running the packages.

Comment: The custom messages always appear in VS in both places mentioned above. I have quite a few of these running in SSIS but none of my messages ever appear when I look at the execution reports. I've not tried this with errors but will do that today to see if they wind up in the logs.